# click to show the random number in each text

Tags: javascript

I want a make a small www using javascript.
![the website interface][1]

I want to when click the button it will show 7 random number in each textbox.
Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script language ="JavaScript">
     function random_number()
    { 
  var i;
  var a=[];
  for(i=0;i<8;i++){
  a +=Math.floor((Math.random()*39)+1);}
  document.getElementByClassName("data").value=a;
  
    } 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Random Number </h1>
<p>
Scol:
<input type="text" class="data" size="3" />
<input type="text" class="data" size="3" />
<input type="text" class="data" size="3" />
<input type="text" class="data" size="3" />
<input type="text" class="data" size="3" />
<input type="text" class="data" size="3" />
<input type="text" class="data" size="3" />

<input type="button" value="Random" onClick="random_number()" />
</p>
</body>

</html>
```

But when i click button, nothing appears, can anyone tell me why?
Thanks!

Comment: Click the button and check your console: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

Comment: Hint: `getElementByClassName` doesn't exist. [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820)

Comment: ... and when corrected, its usage is incorrect.

Comment: @FelixKling we will provide the solution with hints... haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it by `getElementsByTagName`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/9qt73kp1/

```
function random_number() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
        a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 39) + 1);
        inputs[i].value = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks!it works! i use your way to change it to getElementByClassName!It works!Thank you!